# Windows 7 user cannot connect to mapped drives over VPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I have a user that when connected to domain using the windows 7 VPN client, cannot access any of her mapped network drives.

I know it is not a DNS issue because I can ping the servers the drives are located on by hostname, and the drives are mapped by I.P. addresses anyway.

I tried uninstalling the users firewall and connecting to the mapped drives, but no dice.

The only error message I get is "unexpected network error occurred" or no error at all, it just times out.

I tried using the same domain account to connect to the VPN on another machine, and I can access the shared drives just fine.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess VPN settings are blocking traffic from the entry point being used to the network shares. That behavior is what I would expect to see in that instance. If the other PC you accessed the network with was setup on a different VPN entry point, that would explain the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that, but both machines have the VPN configured identically.

Comment: Most VPN clients I've worked with show the name of the entry point in the login screen. If they are configured identically, there may be a problem with the AD account of the PC. Try having another user log in with the problem PC and try to access the network shares.

Comment: It worked doing that

Comment: So let me phrase this so we can be sure we're all on the same page. User 1 on PC 1 connects over VPN, can't access network drives. User 2 on PC 2 connects over VPN, can access network drives. User 1 on PC 2 connects over VPN, can access network drives. User 2 on PC 1 connects over VPN, can access network drives. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this.

Yeah that was correct.

Ended up just connecting to the network drives with different credentials, worked after a few tries.